# jScrollPane missing scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jscrollpane

I've seen the same question over and over here, but no solution worked for me.
I am applying the `jScrollPane()` method on a `<div>` element with settled `height` and `width`, the content is cut by the overflow `jScrollPane()` inserts, but the scroll bar is not appearing.

### My JavaScript code:

```
function openSubs(cont){

    var width = 500;
    var height = 500;
    var mtop = ((height+65)/2)*(-1);

    $('#lightbox .content').width(width).height(height).css('margin-top', mtop).load('content/'+cont+'.php', function(){
        $('#sub-content').width(width).height(height);
        $('#sub-content').jScrollPane();
    });
    openLightBox();

}
```

(on the openLightBox(); function are the fadeIns for the Lightbox divs below)

And the HTML before the Scroll Pane method is called:

```
<div id="lightbox">
    <div class="fade"></div>
    <div class="content">
        A HUGE TEXT GOES HERE
    </div>
    <div class="fechar" onClick="resetLightBox();"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It help users debug more quickly if you can post a jsFiddle for JavaScript questions.

Comment: Yep, we need a fiddle or otherwise we're just guessing. Also, doesn't `openLightBox();` need to be defined somewhere? or is that part of `jScrollPane()` plugin?

Comment: openLightBox is defined. basically it fades in the divs in this html chunk i've posted.